# httpd doesn't receive connections on 500, isakmp does

Tags: apache-httpd, tcpdump

I used to be able to configure apache to start a virtual server on 500 for https. Now when it start it doesn't report any errors and when I netstat -npl I can see that it's listening on 500 plus 443 and 80. When I try to reach it on 500 however I can't. when I execute tcpdump on the port I can see that the service receiving the packets is called .isakmp. How can I resolve this?

output of iptables:

```
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
18532 2028K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  316 18400 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1692  205K INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1692  205K INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1692  205K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
  156  8112 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: Well, `/etc/services` lists isakmp for port 500 tcp and udp, so maybe all you're seeing is tcpdump cross-referencing there. isakmp seems to be some sort of key exchange protocol type of thing.

Comment: You are probably using the packet filter (firewall) which isconfigured to accept packets for ports 80 and 443 but not 500. Add the output of `iptables -L INPUT -nv` to your question.

Comment: So, you see your server listening on port 500, you see requests coming to that port, but what else do you see with `tcpdump`? Are there replies? What does "I can't" mean exactly? Please, add details to your question.

Comment: I can see requests coming on tcpdump but nothing going the other way:

Comment: to @UlrichSchwarz , I don't see a service called isakmp. Do you mean that it's not actually running buy tcpdump is getting the name from the file you mentioned? If so, does that mean something is broken with apache?

Comment: @admdev: tcpdump has an `-n` flag just like `netstat`, which governs if IPs are reverse-resolved to names and port numbers to service names, then you'll probably just see it going to port 500.

Comment: to @UlrichSchwarz I used the option I still see isakmp as the port number after the dot ".". does that say anything? thank you.

Comment: @HaukeLaging you are right. It turns out it is the firewall. I used to enable it for this port manually aside from the regular http. I forgot this time. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the packet filter (firewall) which is configured to accept packets for ports 80 and 443 but not 500 as can be seen by the output of

```
iptables -L INPUT -nv
```